# Asyntask thread does not work when the screen goes to sleep in android

Tags: android

I am using asyntask for sending data(latitude,longitude) to server after every five minutes. But Asyntask thread does not work when the screen goes to sleep in android.I have done it without asyntask but for low internet speed data is sent to server after 8,10 or 12 minutes later randomly.

Comment: you should use service to do this kind of repetitive tasks

Comment: dear set a repeating alarm for every 5 minutes and announce a broadcast that ll send data even in sleep mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask was designed to perform background operations and update UI after it, if the activity is paused, there's no UI to update..so AsyncTask isn't really the best option for your requirement.

You have to combine two 3 components from Android, the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)...in summary, the logic will be like this:

1. You schedule an execution with the AlarmManager
2. You handle the AlarmManager event in a BroadcastReceiver
3. From the BroadcastReceiver you call a service that performs the task of syncing with the server

the item 3 is basically to ensure that the task will be completed in a controlled way until it finishes.

You may follow this example as guidance:
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Answer (score 2):

Though every 5 minutes is pretty aggressive, you should implement a Service for this sort of task.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Here a link for the best practices for background tasks:

https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: this should be comment bro.